# How to insert object inside array in a async function?

Tags: javascript, cordova, async-await

I'm trying to read pdf files from a file system and insert them into array. My code for this purpose is:-

```
let readfiles={
'files':[],
'init':function(cordova){
    readfiles.read(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
    //showfiles.showfiles(readfiles.files);
    console.log(readfiles.files);
},
'readentries':function(entries){
    for(var i=0;i<entries.length;i++){
        if(entries[i].isDirectory===true && entries[i].name.startsWith(".")===false){
            readfiles.read(entries[i].nativeURL);
        }
        else{
            if(entries[i].nativeURL.endsWith(".pdf")===true){
                readfiles.files.push({
                    "url":entries[i].nativeURL,
                    "name":entries[i].name
                });
            }
        }
    }
},
'error':function(err){
    console.log(err);
},
'read':function(path){
    console.log(1);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
        function (fileSystem) {
            console.log(2);
            var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(
                function(entries){readfiles.readentries(entries)},
                function(err){console.log(err);}
            );
        },
        function(err){console.log(err);}
    ).then(res=>{console.log("expected");console.log(res)});
    console.log(3);
}
```

}
Since `readfiles.read()` is a asynchronous recursive function, it didn't wait till its completion, I get length of array as `0` but I want to get length of all results.How can I use `await` for recursive calls too so that I can wait for loop to fetch results.

Comment: You should refactor your code to have multiple functions here

Comment: @Eric Can you provide some code or reference . Most probably it's happening due to asynchronous function, I tried await but still it's not waiting to complete its execution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File size function in cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119250/file-size-function-in-cordova)

Comment: @Eric That answer didn't solve the question because that user is actually trying to find file size after finding file name but I'm looking to add filename into array so that I can apply operation like search, sort etc/

Comment: @Eric I also refactored the code and I believe now it's easy to understand.