# Cordova File Plugin Return Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, plugins

Using the Cordova-file-plugin how do you return the result to a function call.

For example if I call the readFile() like this:
On success I want to return the result back to the function.

```js
<script>
  a0 = readFile();
  alert(a0);

   function readFile(){
      alert("Read File");
      var type = window.PERSISTENT;
      var size = 5*1024*1024;
      window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

      function successCallback(fs) {
        fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
              //var txtArea = document.getElementById('textarea');
              //txtArea.value = this.result;
              abc = JSON.parse(this.result);
              return abc;
              // $("body").append(JSON.parse(this.result));
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
         }, errorCallback);
        }, errorCallback);
      }
      function errorCallback(error) {
        alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
      }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You can't return, we need a callback because you're in an async call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File size function in cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119250/file-size-function-in-cordova)